# Looking for a particular word

Tags: word-request, idiom-request

I'm looking for one word, phrase or idiom that means the following "a female (woman,girl) who did a bad thing but it was cute and amazing, something surprising but not pleasant"

- I invited a girl to have dinner with me at a restaurant, she ordered a lot of food and eat it. I went to the man's room and when I returned she wasn't there. She only left a paper saying "Thanks, good luck".

But what she did didn't make me angry, instead I was intrigued and surprised. I don't blame her but she did a nasty thing.

What is she after that? What do I call her?

I was thinking of **"a charming bitch"** or  **"a lovely bitch"**, **"a glorious wretch"**.

Comment: There are some very nasty words for this, is that what you want? She a con. She 'dined and dashed.'

Comment: Yeh may not be a nasty word.

Comment: She ditched you?

Comment: @StephenS Not me, and no, she made an unpleasant thing which was really cute and impressive. This wasn't bad and the man isn't angry: he's amazed and intrigued.

Comment: Many movies play off of this premise, the game of cat & mouse (or cat & cat) between the two lead characters, where every horrible thing they do to each other just attracts them more.  In fiction [or poetry](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kI3MwwWYC3Q) anything is possible.  :)
However I don't think there is a single word to describe this -- it's too complex a situation to merit anything less than a phrase or metaphor.

Comment: For example "Her behavior was so astonishingly rude, so irreverent and carefree, that it kindled in me a profound fascination.   I had to see her again."

Comment: An intrigue? A mystery? A not-nice person?

Comment: @Andrew Now, please, compile this into one word, short phrase or idiom.

Comment: To me, this is a trait of most gamines. :-)

Comment: @DamkerngT. I think that's super close to what I need. She's really an elegant young woman, a pert girl who is mischievous, playful, teasing and sexually appealing but no boyish.

Comment: @SovereignSun how about *femme fatale*?

Comment: @Andrew Another good, possible word!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're looking for a word that's less offensive, you could use **vixen**. It often means a woman who is devious but in an intriguing or sexy way. A dictionary defines it as:

> 1. a female fox
> 2. a shrewish, ill-tempered woman
> 3. a sexually attractive woman

https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/vixen

The word "shrewish" is a more old fashioned and less offensive synonym for "bitchy."

With the other examples you gave, you could make them less offensive by using the word "**devil**," as "she-devil" is slang for a devious woman in English.

> A charming **devil**.
>   A lovely **devil**.

Also, in your specific example, where she left in the middle of dinner, an affectionate term would be "**tease**," as in:

> She was a real **tease**.

Another word that refers to a mischievous but charming woman is **gamine**:

> a girl with mischievous or boyish charm.

In the comments, the term "femme fatale" was brought up. In literature, the word **femme fatale** often refers to a woman who is seductive but leads a man to disaster or misfortune.  This term would most likely be used when analyzing or discussing a story, as it is more of a literary term than the others.  The term derives from French for "fatal woman."

In your case, **femme fatale** is probably not as appropriate because the female was mischievous, but did not lead you to any harm.

Comment: Please include gamine and femme fatale in your answer.

Comment: @SovereignSun I added those terms to the answer, but I believe that "femme fatale" is not quite appropriate for this situation, because it refers to a woman who ultimately leads a man to disaster or harm.  It means "fatal woman" in French.  Since your situation did not involve danger or harm, you would probably be better off using a word like **vixen** than **femme fatale**.  For more see the edit to my answer.